# Selenium webdriver getting focus to parent window from child window whichis pop

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to switch to parent window from pop-up window which is generated by a click.

I have tried some methods which I found but non of them worked.

```
public static String validateHierarchy(Properties prop)
{
    String Hierarchy = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[34]/td")).getText();
    Log.info(Hierarchy);

    String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class='left-link']")).get(10).click();
    //switching to current window 
    Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println("Window"+mainWindowHandle);
    System.out.println("Window"+s);
    Iterator<String> ite = s.iterator();
    while(ite.hasNext())
    {
        String popupHandle=ite.next().toString();
        if(!popupHandle.contains(mainWindowHandle))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
            //checking for forgot password text in the current page
            String part1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/form")).getText();
            Log.info(part1);
            String part2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tree']")).getText();
            Log.info(part2);

            driver.close(); //closing child window
        }
    }

     driver.switchTo().window( mainWindowHandle );

    String mainWindowHandle1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Window"+mainWindowHandle1);
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class='left-link']")).get(11).click();




    //switching to current window 
    Set <String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println("Window"+mainWindowHandle1);
    System.out.println("Window"+s1);
    Iterator<String> ite1 = s1.iterator();
    while(ite1.hasNext())
    {
        String popupHandle1=ite1.next().toString();
        if(!popupHandle1.contains(mainWindowHandle1))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle1);

            //checking for forgot password text in the current page
            String part1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/form")).getText();
            Log.info(part1);
            String part2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tree']")).getText();
            Log.info(part2);



            driver.close(); //closing child window

         }
      }


    driver.switchTo().window( mainWindowHandle );
    return Hierarchy;
}
```

The first pop-up is handled properly but when it comes out of that and goes to the click option "get(11).click()". It gets error there saying

> Window{ed1019d1-0ac5-4cc0-ba18-8efdadc10c4c}
>   Window[{ed1019d1-0ac5-4cc0-ba18-8efdadc10c4c}, {9e9cbcf5-9c4b-4805-918b-8f3eb7d9f946}]
>   Window{ed1019d1-0ac5-4cc0-ba18-8efdadc10c4c}
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 0
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>       at JaamoonManage.validateHierarchy(JaamoonManage.java:299)
>       at JaamoonManage.main(JaamoonManage.java:106)

Even i also tried to find the String Hierarchy element but i was not able to find that also. It is switching to the parent window but it is not able to do any on that.

Can someone point out where i am having problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer this blog post http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-switch-control-to-pop-up-window.html

Comment: I have tried that 1 st method but it didnt help..

Comment: I don't understand how i am getting IndexOutOfBoundException

Answer (score 0):

Reason for getting IndexOutOfBoundException is, there was no 11th element with this locator ***By.cssSelector("a[class='left-link']")***

[get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method in List will returns the element at the specified position in this list and throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

Check your logic at below step once again.

```
 driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class='left-link']")).get(11).click();
```

Refer [this blog](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-switch-control-to-pop-up-window.html) to for switching control to child window.

Comment: if i comment the first                                                                                      " driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[class='left-link']")).get(10).click(); "  and the pop-up function, then the 11 element works fine. There are more 'left-link' element on 12 13 and 14. If i comment this whole method then 12 13 and 14 element work fine in another method. The problem is only coming when i getting back from pop-up and try to access another element after closing the pop.

Comment: Is it switching the control to main window correctly first time? Make sure that by printing page title/current url after switching the control to main window (after closing the first popup). and also try to get(11) element after refreshing the window using driver.navigate().refresh();

Comment: yes it is switching to the main window correctly.
you can see in my question i have used System.out.println to track the handlers.
In the console I can see the handler in the end is the main handler.

I didn't understand what you meant by the printing page title/current url can you please explain??

I will try to with refresh function and tell you..

Comment: I'm just asking you to print System.out.println(driver.getTitle()), to make sure that control properly changed to main window again after closing the first popup.

Comment: yes SOP is getting the main window as the title. I did find a solution. But it is not a actual solution but a workaround you can say. After closing the pop-up from get(10).click(); . I am doing now is

  driver.navigate().refresh();
  Integer TIME1 = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(TIME));
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TIME1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
  WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.id(MAIN));
  driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage")).click();
  
  
 and then clicking the 11 element. It is working fine but it isnt a great solution.

Comment: what did you find ? Is that working with your solution ?

Comment: yes see this code. driver.close(); //closing child window
  driver.switchTo().window( mainWindowHandle ); 
  
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());  this printed the main window which i check when i logged in. Yes this is working now. But It has increased the code a lot. i feel this is not a proper solution which I made but working working around.

Comment: You mean, after adding System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); this step it is working. If it so, it must work without that statement also.

Comment: No I didn't mean it working after adding that SOP. BUT I meant that I can see the main window name using SOP. But the code I gave this which I used after closing the pop-up of 10 element and before clicking 11 element.
This code make it work.

driver.navigate().refresh(); Integer TIME1 = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(TIME)); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TIME1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.id(MAIN)); driver.switchTo().frame(frame); driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage")).click();